# finding factors of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

In the math problem in the attached image, it explains how to find the factors of a polynomial whereby every possible factor of the function is of the form p/q, where "p is a factor of the constant term" and q is a factor of the leading coefficient. In the example given, the constant term is 9 and the leading coefficient is 3. Question, why does it list 1/3 and 1/9 as possible factors? Neither of those are factors of 9 or 3
[image]

Comment: 1/9.-1/9 should be excluded. Neither  can be written as a factor of 9 over a factor of 3. Is not it?

Comment: but it can be that $x_0\ne 0$ is not a factor but $\frac{1}{x_0}$

Comment: I'm thinking it must be a typo on the part of the textbook creators

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can choose $p=\pm1$ and $q=3$ to find that $\pm\frac 1 3$ is a possible zero of your polynomial.
Indeed, $\pm\frac 1 9$ cannot be a rational zero.